# OpenCV - How to project RGB image to log (R/G) ~ log (B/G) space?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, logarithm, color-space

I am trying to project an RGB image to **log (R/G) ~ log (B/G)** coordinate system.

According to the definition [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11760-019-01596-0) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402619304954) the log (R/G) ~ log (B/G) space is calculated like this:

[image]

Basically, I want two arrays X and Y (I use Mat as an array) where:

[image]

[image]

This is what I have tried:

#### calculating X* and Y*:

```c
    Mat input = imread("an RGB image");
    Mat X, Y, B, G, R, input_f;
    input.convertTo(input_f, CV_32FC3);
    vector<Mat> channels(3);
    split(input_f, channels);
    B = channels[0];
    G = channels[1];
    R = channels[2];

    //-- calculate X , Y vectors
    Mat div_x, div_y;
    divide(R, G, div_x);
    divide(B, G, div_y);
    log(div_x, X);
    log(div_y, Y);
    X.setTo(0, Mat(X < 0));
    Y.setTo(0, Mat(Y < 0));

    //-- calculate X* , Y* vectors
    Mat X_star, Y_star;
    Scalar x_bar = mean(X);
    Scalar y_bar = mean(Y); 

    subtract(X, Scalar(x_bar), X_star);
    subtract(Y, Scalar(y_bar), Y_star);
```

But when I try the rest of the instructions to obtain the result, my result does not look like theirs at all.

[image]

#### calculating the intrinsic image:

```c
    Mat intrinsic;
    intrinsic = X * cos(alpha) + Y * sin(alpha);
    imshow("intrinsic", intrinsic);
```

I think I am doing something wrong in calculating the `X*` and `Y*` matrices. Because when I try this with any value of `alpha` the result dows not become right:

This is the image:

[image]

This is the expected result:

[image]

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the first paper:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small question (sorry, I can't comment yet):

Shouldn't the `X`

```
intrinsic = X * cos(alpha) + Y * sin(alpha);
```

be `X_star` instead?

```
intrinsic = X_star * cos(alpha) + Y_star * sin(alpha);
```

Otherwise you could write `subtract(X, Scalar(x_bar), X);`

And how to you compute α?

**Edit**
[image]

This is a screenshot from your [2nd posted source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402619304954).

As you can see, the gray-scale image G inv is computed by means of your `X_star`:  `intrinsic = X_star * cos(alpha) + Y_star * sin(alpha);`.
This also the case for the first equation you posted.

I can not access the first link you posted, it is not free.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but according to the last formula the intrinsic image is supposed to be calculated based on `X` and `Y`. `X*` and `Y*` are just to calculate the right `alpha`. To calculate `alpha` we have: `alpha = arctan(sign(cov(X*,Y*)) * sum(abs(Y)) / sum(abs(X))`. But I know the calculation of `logarithms` is wrong, because the result is not correct for any `alpha`.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, the calculation of `X` and `Y` is based on subtracting `x_bar`, resp. `y_bar` from `X`, resp. `Y`. This is your `X_star`and `Y_star`

Comment: I added a screenshot of the first paper. My implementation is based on that. But the result is wrong for all values of `alpha` so there should be something wrong with the logarithm.

Comment: You missed the first sentence in b) "The vectors `X` and `Y` are removed the centers".
This is what is computed in your `X_star` and `Y_star`: you remove the center (mean) from `X` and `Y`

Comment: I tried to use `intrinsic = X_star * cos(alpha) + Y_star * sin(alpha);` to calculate `intrinsic` image, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: You MUST use your `X_star` and `Y_star` to compute I_inv.
For `x*` and `y*` you must compute the mean of `X_star` and `Y_star` and compute `x* = X_star - mean(X_star)`. The same holds for `y*`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the formula to `intrinsic = X_star * cos(alpha) + Y_star * sin(alpha);` as you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208650/discussion-between-geoidiot-and-hadi-ghahremannezhad).